# Apache 2.2. Basic Auth, Force Prompt

Tags: basic-authentication, prompt, unauthorized, apache2.2

I have a protected directory for downloads.

A protected file in /downloads has this header:

WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Downloads"

I'm protecting it with .htaccess:

```
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthName "Downloads"
<Limit GET>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Require valid-user
Allow from 192.168.1.2
Satisfy any
</Limit>
```

If I'm not coming from 192.168.1.2, I need to auth via LDAP, or upon auth failure, receive a 401 not authorized message.

Sometimes, when not on 192.168.1.2, it seems I receive the 401 error without a prompt for credentials when trying to download a file for the first time in a browser.

A reload will bring the auth prompt. It's as if the server thinks the browser has tried and failed to auth.

But I'm certain that's not the case, as it's the first visit since opening the browser. It doesn't always happen.

When I notice the issue, I usually have logged in, via SSO, to a different site prior, e.g., foo.bar.com, a sub-domain of the site with the downloads.  The site with the downloads, www.bar.com, does not share SSO with foo.bar.com.

Additionally, people following a link to the download click on an HTTP link, but the download site redirects to HTTPS (and any credential request is over HTTPS), the site uses HSTS to encourage HTTPS other times. I'm not sure if this could be related.

Is there some way I can always force the prompt (assuming I'm not at 192.168.1.2)? Can I do something with a rewrite and an auth header?

Any idea why I'm not always prompted for credentials?